# As part of Stokes' Thm, do we need to show $\partial M$ is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, manifolds, compactness, stokes-theorem

I am reading *Analysis on Manifolds* by Munkres, this is from Section 37 
 **Stokes' Theorem**: Let M be a compact oriented $k$-manifold in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open s.t. $M \subseteq A$, $\omega$ a $(k-1)$-form defined on $A$

- If $\partial M \neq \emptyset$, give it the induced orientation, then $\int_M d \omega =\int_{ \partial M} \omega$

  If $\partial M = \emptyset$, then $\int_M d \omega$=0.

I just have a bookkeeping question: in order to show this, do we need to show $M$ compact implies $\partial M$ is compact?  Munkres only defines integrals of $k$-forms over compact, so it seems we need that to make sense of $\int_{ \partial M} \omega$.  But it's not mentioned in the proof, and looking back through earlier sections I don't think Munkres mentions it either.  Since I am new to this subject, I am genuinely confused.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The boundary is a closed set, and closed subsets of compact sets are still compact.

Comment: The boundary of a manifold is always a relatively closed subset. So, if the manifold is compact, the boundary is compact as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $M$ is a manifold with boundary, then the interior of $M$ is an open set (since every point has a neighborhood diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$, and then every point in that neighborhood is also in the interior).  So the boundary $\partial M$ is a closed subset of $M$.  If $M$ is compact, this means $\partial M$ is automatically compact as well.